# Deny Bot access to server

Tags: php, security, windows-phone, bots

i have a windows phone app that can send to a php a registration for one account. One user with this app can create max. 3 account..
But i'm wrong or an hacker can't find the php link where i send the registration?
Because i wrote the link for this php just in the code where i think an hacker can't access (wp is secure, or i'm wrong?)

If i'm wrong how can i deny hackers to register infinite times with this php page?
If im not wrong and an hacker can't get the xap where the code is, i can just use no protection for the php right?

Comment: Use `captch` verification.

Comment: is this necessary? i think users can't know php link cause of wp security